# Criar function para atualizar coluna

Tags: postgresql, funções, parâmetros

Preciso atualizar uma coluna de acordo com o conteúdo de outras duas colunas, por exemplo, possuo duas tabelas, a tabela `suprimentos` e a tabela `estoque`,

**Tabela suprimentos**
`codigoSuprimento`
`capacidadeSuprimento`

**Tabela Estoque**
`codigoSuprimento`
`capacidadeUsada`
`percentualUsado`

Digamos que na tabela `suprimentos` eu possua o seguinte cadastro:

```
codigoSuprimento | capacidadeSuprimento
       1         |         1000
```

E na tabela `estoque` o seguinte cadastro:

```
codigoSuprimento | capacidadeUsada | percentualUsado
       1         |        300      |         X
```

Minha necessidade é criar uma **function** para que a coluna `percentualUsado` seja preenchida de acordo com a `capacidadeUsada` em cima da `capacidadeSuprimento`. Seria `capacidadeUsada` x `100` / `capacidadeSuprimento`. Porém não sei como fazer isso em uma **Function**, colocar esse conteúdo em parâmetros para conseguir realizar esse calculo que é uma incógnita para mim.

Comment: Me explica uma coisa, você não poderia fazer subselect para Inserção na tabela estoque,
Exemplo:` INSERT INTO estoque (codigoSuprimento,capacidadeUsada,percentualUsado)
(1,300,(SELECT 300*100/(capacidadeSuprimento) FROM suprimento WHERE codigoSuprimento = 1))`
este é só um pequeno exemplo, para que você possa organizar melhor sua linha de raciocinio.

Comment: @MarcusItalo, obrigado pela dica, porém ontem analisando minha necessidade, percebi que não haveria necessidade de saber a porcentagem que o suprimento foi usado pois o fato de saber a capacidade usado já resolve meu problema, as vezes é necessári apenas desfocar um pouco do problema para descobrir que a resposta esta bem na cara, mas novamente obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_suprimento
(
    cod INTEGER,
    capacidade INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE tb_estoque
(
    cod_suprimento INTEGER,
    capacidade_usada INTEGER,
    percentual_usado INTEGER
);
```

Contendo os seguintes dados:

```
INSERT INTO tb_suprimento ( cod, capacidade ) VALUES ( 1, 1000 );
INSERT INTO tb_suprimento ( cod, capacidade ) VALUES ( 2, 500 );
INSERT INTO tb_suprimento ( cod, capacidade ) VALUES ( 3, 300 );
INSERT INTO tb_suprimento ( cod, capacidade ) VALUES ( 4, 750 );
INSERT INTO tb_suprimento ( cod, capacidade ) VALUES ( 5, 400 );

INSERT INTO tb_estoque ( cod_suprimento, capacidade_usada ) VALUES ( 1, 300 );
INSERT INTO tb_estoque ( cod_suprimento, capacidade_usada ) VALUES ( 2, 100 );
INSERT INTO tb_estoque ( cod_suprimento, capacidade_usada ) VALUES ( 3, 120 );
INSERT INTO tb_estoque ( cod_suprimento, capacidade_usada ) VALUES ( 4, 50 );
INSERT INTO tb_estoque ( cod_suprimento, capacidade_usada ) VALUES ( 5, 400 );
```

Função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_atualizar_estoque( INTEGER )
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        tb_estoque
    SET
        percentual_usado = (100 * capacidade_usada) / tb_suprimento.capacidade 
    FROM
        tb_suprimento
    WHERE
        tb_suprimento.cod = $1 AND
        tb_estoque.cod_suprimento = $1;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Testando:

```
SELECT fc_atualizar_estoque(1);
SELECT fc_atualizar_estoque(2);
SELECT fc_atualizar_estoque(3);
SELECT fc_atualizar_estoque(4);
SELECT fc_atualizar_estoque(5);
```

Com Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_atualizar_estoque()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    cap INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT capacidade FROM tb_suprimento WHERE cod = NEW.cod_suprimento INTO cap;
    NEW.percentual_usado = (100 * NEW.capacidade_usada) / cap;
    RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_atualizar_estoque BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tb_estoque FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fc_atualizar_estoque();
```

Comment: Eu conseguiria ativar essa function com uma trigger?